# How to dynamically update progress bar while doing database query with delay of 1 second in PHP bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

as per the subject, I would like to update a progress bar upon execution of each SQL insert statements with a delay of 1 seconds in between. How do i do that? I have the static bootstrap code here but unable to make it update dynamically ... I tried created a proof of concept code with the following by trying to do a loop but it shows 5 progress bar instead of 1 that is constantly updating.

Below is the code I tried with :

```html
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $counter;?>%">
      <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've provided no relevant code and not even much idea of what you're trying to do other than *insert things into the database".  There's really very little to work with here as a question, please try to improve it.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have totally no clue to starting off other than the static code that i managed to find. Thats why im here dude

Answer (score 0):

You will need JQuery/AJAX to achieve such thing.
Here is a perfect example of how to update the progressbar via an AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var progresspump = setInterval(function(){
    /* query the completion percentage from the server */
    $.get("/app/update-progress", function(data){
      /* update the progress bar width */
      $("#progress").css('width',data+'%');
      /* and display the numeric value */
      $("#progress").html(data+'%');

      /* test to see if the job has completed */
      if(data > 99.999) {
        clearInterval(progresspump);
        $("#progressouter").removeClass("active");
        $("#progress").html("Done");
      }
    })
  }, 1000);});
```

More info [here](http://elfga.com/blog/2012/10/03/bootstrap-progress-bar-update-jqueryajax/)

The URL refers to the action called update-progress. You can either create another service which checks the row count, or a javascript funtion in the while() for example:

```
while(doThings()) {
    echo '<script> updateProgress("' . $x .'%");</script>';
    flush();
}
```

Also I found an example on [this](http://effectivewebdesigns.blogspot.nl/2014/04/twitter-bootstrap-progress-bar-example.html#.VG29ri55PZ4) page. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: There's also a server-side component to this which you haven't touched on.  How is the update-progress server script meant to know which query the progress request is for, and how far the query has progressed?

Comment: could you elaborate further? Is there proof of concept code i could refer to ? I'm new to AJAX

Comment: @GordonM the URL refers to the action called update-progress. You can either create another service which checks the row count, or a javascript funtion in the while() for example.